# How i can change SQL in order to to avoid DISTINCT and 2 fields in WHERE?

Tags: sql, oracle

here is my SQL, 
I want to get rid of WHERE (ADDRESS_KEY, PRIO). How I can say it with JOIN?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ADDRESS_KEY, ADDRESS_LINE_1, ADDRESS_LINE_2, ADDRESS_LINE_3, CITY, COUNTRY_CD, IS_TO_BE_DELETED, STREET, ROW_UPDATE_DATE
FROM V_CUSTACCHOLD
WHERE (ADDRESS_KEY, PRIO) IN (SELECT DISTINCT ADDRESS_KEY, MIN(PRIO) FROM V_CUSTACCHOLD GROUP BY ADDRESS_KEY)
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the table to the query you use in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ADDRESS_KEY, ADDRESS_LINE_1, ADDRESS_LINE_2, ADDRESS_LINE_3, CITY, COUNTRY_CD, IS_TO_BE_DELETED, STREET, ROW_UPDATE_DATE
FROM V_CUSTACCHOLD v1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT ADDRESS_KEY, MIN(PRIO) PRIO FROM V_CUSTACCHOLD GROUP BY ADDRESS_KEY) v2
ON v2.ADDRESS_KEY = v1.ADDRESS_KEY AND v2.PRIO = v1.PRIO
```

You may remove `DISTINCT` from `SELECT` depending on the results.

Answer (score 0):

You have a view, so I would recommend window functions:

```
SELECT CA.*
FROM (SELECT CA.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ADDRESS_KEY ORDER BY PRIO ASC) AS SEQNUM
      FROM V_CUSTACCHOLD CA
     ) CA
WHERE SEQNUM = 1;
```

Comment: @Erlica . . . I fixed the typo.  For a view, I strongly recommend using window functions.